# Car model in HTML5 game

Tags: html, canvas

I need advice what need I do. Now I'm developing browser race game and I'd like to use there vector model of car with the help of Inkscape in Ubuntu, I'd also like the point of view was first person.
In general i need a vector picture/model of Mercedes Sprinter (also from this point of view), so I'm ready to find it at streets of our city and to make few photo of good quality. How do May I know your opinion how do I need proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could:

1. Ask Google for an image of a "Mercedes Sprinter driver perspective" or do as you suggest and ask a Sprinter owner to let you take some pictures from their driver seat.
2. Use Inkscape's trace function to create paths from that image:
   http://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html
3. Use one of the online svg-to-canvas converters to get canvas paths to use in your game:
   http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/